# stack from NativeStackNavigator (nested in BottomTabNavigator) resets everytime the BottomTabNavigator changes tabs

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation, react-navigation-stack, react-navigation-bottom-tab

***Situation:***
The react native app has a BottomTabNavigator (react-navigation/material-bottom-tabs) and one of the tabs has a NativeStackNavigator (react-navigation/native-stack).

```
BottomTabNavigator:
   tab1
   tab2
   tab3:
      NativeStackNavigator:
         screen1
         screen2
```

***Problem:***
When I press tab3 (from the BottomTabNavigator) I see screen 1.
If I press a button on screen 1 then it will navigate from screen 1 to screen 2.
When I press tab1 or tab2 and then I press tab3 again then I see screen 1. 
**I want to see screen 2 (because that's what should be at the top of the stack from the NativeStackNavigator right?).**
Did the stack from NativeStackNavigator reset?
Did the whole NativeStackNavigator render again?
What causes this behavior?

Code BottomTabNavigator:

```
export type MainNavigationBarParam = {
  tab1: undefined;
  tab2: undefined;
  tab3: undefined;
};

const Tab = getMainNavigationBarTabNavigator();

export const tab3Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();

export function MainNavigationBar() {
  const sizeToUse = 25;
  return (
    <Tab.Navigator
      screenOptions={defaultScreenOptions()}
      barStyle={{backgroundColor: theme.colors.primary}}>
      <Tab.Screen
        name="tab1"
        component={Component1}
      />
      <Tab.Screen
        name="tab2"
        component={Component2}
      />
      <Tab.Screen
        name="tab3"
        component={Component3}
      />
    </Tab.Navigator>
  );
}
function defaultScreenOptions() {
  const screenOptions: any = {
    headerShown: false,
    tabBarHideOnKeyboard: true,
  };
  if (Platform.OS === 'web') {
    screenOptions.swipeEnabled = false;
  }
  return screenOptions;
}
```

Code Component3:

```
export type Tab3Stack ParamList = {
  Screen1: undefined;
  Screen2: {id: string; name: string};
};

export default function Component3() {
  const [topComponentHeight, setTopComponentHeight] = useState(0);

  function onLayout(event: LayoutChangeEvent) {
    if ('top' in event.nativeEvent.layout) {
      const withTop = event.nativeEvent.layout as unknown as {top: number};
      setTopComponentHeight(withTop.top);
    }
    event;
  }

  return (
    <View style={navContainerStyle(topComponentHeight).navContainer} onLayout={onLayout}>
      <tab3Stack.Navigator screenOptions={{headerShown: false}}>
        <tab3Stack.Screen
          name={'Screen1'}
          component={Screen1}
        />
        <tab3Stack.Screen
          name={'Screen2'}
          component={Screen2}
        />
      </tab3Stack.Navigator>
    </View>
  );
}
```

## Update 1

Reproduced the code above for 2 tabs: https://snack.expo.dev/@jacobdel/182747
The problem does not occur on snack, only in my app.

### Console in chrome:

No errors or warnings.
Sometimes this is shown, but after disabling the quill editor it doesn't appear anymore
[image]

## Update 2

Cause is found: `getMainNavigationBarTabNavigator();` from BottomTabNavigator 
File MainNavigationBarTabNavigator.ts looks like this:

```
import {createMaterialBottomTabNavigator} from '@react-navigation/material-bottom-tabs';
import {MainNavigationBarParam} from './MainNavigationTabs';

export function getMainNavigationBarTabNavigator() {
  return createMaterialBottomTabNavigator<MainNavigationBarParam>();
}
```

While MainNavigationBarTabNavigator.web.ts looks like this:

```
import {createMaterialTopTabNavigator} from '@react-navigation/material-top-tabs';
import {MainNavigationBarParam} from './MainNavigationTabs';

export function getMainNavigationBarTabNavigator() {
  return createMaterialTopTabNavigator<MainNavigationBarParam>();
}
```

Snack only works as intended when using MainNavigationBarTabNavigator.ts

## Update 3

Stuck.. 
Replacing the code from MainNavigationBarTabNavigator.web.ts with the code from MainNavigationBarTabNavigator.ts does not show the intended behavior as shown in the Snack example.

[image]

Comment: Are you using `unmountOnBlur: true` option? check your `defaultScreenOptions()`

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but sadly no (I added the defaultScreenOptions() function)

Comment: Could you create a minimal snack so that we can reproduce this issue? I do not see whats wrong in the provided snippets.

Comment: @DavidScholz the problem does not occur on snack: https://snack.expo.dev/@jacobdel/182747
However, I don't see any errors in the console that would suggest a crash in my app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seems to be an issue with the navigation event handling of `@react-navigation/material-top-tabs`.

If we handle this on our own, then the nested stack is not reset. We can prevent the default navigation action by using a `tabPress` event listener and calling `e.preventDefault`.

In your case, this is done as follows for `screen2` (which is the nested stack).

```js
<Tab.Screen
        name="screen2"
        component={Screen2}
        listeners={({ navigation, route }) => ({
        tabPress: (e) => {
            e.preventDefault();
            navigation.navigate({ name: route.name, merge: true });            
         },
    })}
/>
```

Notice that this works fine on the phone, but has some issues on the web. If we navigate **fast** between `screen2` and `screen1` multiple times, then the navigation does not work at all. I haven't found the root cause for this issue.

However, we can make this work on the web as well as on the phone by providing a custom top navigation bar using the `tabBar` prop of the tab navigator. We override the default behavior of the `tabPress` function.

The original component is exported and is named [MaterialTopTabBar](https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/blob/main/packages/material-top-tabs/src/views/MaterialTopTabBar.tsx). Sadly, it does not provide the possibility to provide a custom `onTabPress` function via props.

I have forked the component and 'fixed' (without knowing what exactly is going wrong here) the `onTabPress` function.

```js
import {
  useTheme,
} from '@react-navigation/native';

import Color from 'color';
import * as React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import { TabBar, TabBarIndicator } from 'react-native-tab-view';

export default function FixedTabBarTop({
  state,
  navigation,
  descriptors,
  ...rest
}) {
  const { colors } = useTheme();

  const focusedOptions = descriptors[state.routes[state.index].key].options;

  const activeColor = focusedOptions.tabBarActiveTintColor ?? colors.text;
  const inactiveColor =
    focusedOptions.tabBarInactiveTintColor ??
    new Color(activeColor).alpha(0.5).rgb().string();

  return (
    <TabBar
      {...rest}
      navigationState={state}
      scrollEnabled={focusedOptions.tabBarScrollEnabled}
      bounces={focusedOptions.tabBarBounces}
      activeColor={activeColor}
      inactiveColor={inactiveColor}
      pressColor={focusedOptions.tabBarPressColor}
      pressOpacity={focusedOptions.tabBarPressOpacity}
      tabStyle={focusedOptions.tabBarItemStyle}
      indicatorStyle={[
        { backgroundColor: colors.primary },
        focusedOptions.tabBarIndicatorStyle,
      ]}
      indicatorContainerStyle={focusedOptions.tabBarIndicatorContainerStyle}
      contentContainerStyle={focusedOptions.tabBarContentContainerStyle}
      style={[{ backgroundColor: colors.card }, focusedOptions.tabBarStyle]}
      getAccessibilityLabel={({ route }) =>
        descriptors[route.key].options.tabBarAccessibilityLabel
      }
      getTestID={({ route }) => descriptors[route.key].options.tabBarTestID}
      onTabPress={({ route }) => {
        const event = navigation.emit({
            type: 'tabPress',
            target: route.key,
            canPreventDefault: true,
          });
          if (!event.defaultPrevented) {
            navigation.navigate({ name: route.name, merge: true });
          }
      }}
      onTabLongPress={({ route }) =>
        navigation.emit({
          type: 'tabLongPress',
          target: route.key,
        })
      }
      renderIcon={({ route, focused, color }) => {
        const { options } = descriptors[route.key];

        if (options.tabBarShowIcon === false) {
          return null;
        }

        if (options.tabBarIcon !== undefined) {
          const icon = options.tabBarIcon({ focused, color });

          return (
            <View style={[styles.icon, options.tabBarIconStyle]}>{icon}</View>
          );
        }

        return null;
      }}
      renderLabel={({ route, focused, color }) => {
        const { options } = descriptors[route.key];

        if (options.tabBarShowLabel === false) {
          return null;
        }

        const label =
          options.tabBarLabel !== undefined
            ? options.tabBarLabel
            : options.title !== undefined
            ? options.title
            : route.name;

        if (typeof label === 'string') {
          return (
            <Text
              style={[styles.label, { color }, options.tabBarLabelStyle]}
              allowFontScaling={options.tabBarAllowFontScaling}
            >
              {label}
            </Text>
          );
        }

        return label({ focused, color });
      }}
      renderBadge={({ route }) => {
        const { tabBarBadge } = descriptors[route.key].options;

        return tabBarBadge?.() ?? null;
      }}
      renderIndicator={({ navigationState: state, ...rest }) => {
        return focusedOptions.tabBarIndicator ? (
          focusedOptions.tabBarIndicator({
            state: state,
            ...rest,
          })
        ) : (
          <TabBarIndicator navigationState={state} {...rest} />
        );
      }}
    />
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  icon: {
    height: 24,
    width: 24,
  },
  label: {
    textAlign: 'center',
    textTransform: 'uppercase',
    fontSize: 13,
    margin: 4,
    backgroundColor: 'transparent',
  },
});
```

I have used it as follows.

```js
export function MainNavigationBar() {
  return (
    <Tab.Navigator
      tabBar={props => <FixedTabBarTop {...props} />}
      screenOptions={defaultScreenOptions()}>
      <Tab.Screen
        name="screen1"
        component={Screen1}
      />
      <Tab.Screen
        name="screen2"
        component={Screen2}
      />
    </Tab.Navigator>
  );
}
```

I have [updated your snack](https://snack.expo.dev/@pgrepds/stackoverflow-nativestacknavigator). You might want to submit an issue on GitHub as well. It feels like a bug.

Comment: https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/10755